# Windows 8 laptop won't shut down

Tags: windows-8, laptop, shutdown

Recently- just over the last day or two- my laptop (HP Split running Windows 8) has not been shutting down whenever I click 'Shut Down' on the power options...
Whenever I click 'Shut Down', it appears to start doing this (applications close, screen goes black, however the power never actually shuts down... after a little while, I click the mouse/ press a button on the keyboard, and the screen shows the 'locked' page- so I enter in my password, and am taken to the desktop again.

I have no trouble putting the laptop in 'Sleep', but for some reason it won't shut down. I can't think of any changes that I've made that would cause this... anyone have any ideas? How can I fix it?

Comment: This may sound stupid but, are you sure?
Windows 8 is pretty good at starting fast, especially with an SSD / SSHD as the system drive. The 'Locked'-page is shown when you start up your laptop, and maybe yours is just set up to start by any input activity? Take a look into your bios and see if there's such an option

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I do have an SSD as the system drive- so the laptop does start up pretty fast when I turn it on. Sorry- I don't follow your logic... there has been no input at all after clicking 'Shut Down'... the laptop appears to start shutting down as I've described in my OP, but the power never actually turns off (I can hear that the fan never stops running...) After leaving it alone for 10 minutes, and coming back to find the fan still running, I press a key on the keyboard, and am presented with the 'locked' page...

Comment: Have you tried to turning off 'fast start up' under power settings? It is known to sometimes cause trouble for shutdowns.

Comment: Hold the windows key and press "R", Type this: 'SHUTDOWN /F /S /T 0' 
Press Enter. Let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried restarting the laptop, and then shutting it down after it had restarted- and this worked. I don't know whether there was some process that was running that was preventing the laptop from shutting down, and restarting actually killed that process...? Either way- problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to "C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -s -t 00"

Launch the shortcut.

Is it better ?

Answer (score 0):

After searching I am finding that a lot of people say to disable the paging file, reboot, then re-enable it.

--UPDATE--

I worked for me!    The procedure is easy.  Shut off the paging file, reboot, re-enable it, reboot, and then the problem just magically goes away.

The answer is spelled out here:

[After the latest Win8.1x64 Updates, my system got stuck restarting or shutting down..](https://superuser.com/questions/1211231/after-the-latest-win8-1x64-updates-my-system-got-stuck-restarting-or-shutting-d)

Comment: Keep your answers focused on solving OPs problem, not on attempting to drag people to come have a look at your problem. If you want people to look at your problem then you can post a bounty on it after a day or two.  Perhaps you need to take a look at the [tour] to find out how things work here.

Comment: OK, it is now proven.  Take a look here and check out the answer.  It worked!   https://superuser.com/questions/1211231/after-the-latest-win8-1x64-updates-my-system-got-stuck-restarting-or-shutting-d  - and linking these questions together is good for people doing searches.  I don't do bounties, by the way.  I solve problems instead.

Comment: Well, one of the problems you *created* rather than solved was a lot of comment noise on posts in the form of you 1) begging people to look at your problem, and 2) constantly telling people to take the tour. So please keep your comments relevant, to the point and read our [advice on using comments](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).  Specifically read the **When should I comment?** section: *You should submit a comment if you want to:  - Request clarification from the author; - Leave constructive criticism; - Add relevant but minor or transient information*