# After the latest Win8.1x64 Updates, my system got stuck restarting or shutting down..

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, shutdown, reboot, paging

When I installed the last Windows update, all seemed fine except it got stuck doing the restart.  I waited about 5 minutes then used the power button.

Startup was normal.

But then when I told it to shut down it closed the programs then went to the "Shutting Down" screen and just stays there.

Disk activity lights aren't showing any activity.

Here is a screen grab of the most recent updates:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Before I do anything I wanted some input.

Question:  Any ideas of how I can figure out how to fix it?

Comment: uninstall the latest updates from May and look what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by using Google into StackExchange.  Turns out this is a more common problem than I thought, affecting multiple versions of Windows starting with Vista.  After reading all the posts I could find there was one common theme:  Memory management.

For my situation it turned out to be a paging file problem.

The solution that worked is pretty simple:

1. Click on the **Start** button (I use Classic Shell so it looks like a Windows 7 menu), then right-click on **This PC** and select **Properties**.  Click on **Advanced System Settings**, then the **Advanced** tab and select **Performance Settings**, then pick the **Advanced** tab.  Under **Virtual Memory** select **Change**.
2. Set it to **No paging file**.  Then **OK**, **OK**, **OK**.
3. Shut down.  Even if it means waiting 30 seconds after it closes apps and services and disk activity stops then using the power button.
4. When the system comes back up, do it all again but this time select **System managed** size.
5. Then another shutdown and startup.

It made a big difference.  Apparently it just needed to rebuild the paging file.

Problem solved for me.

*(Which kinda begs another question:  My system is 16 GB RAM and I tend to use about half of that so I wonder why Windows needs it at all?  But that's a question for another day.  Or not.  System managed is fine)*